# What is the physical interpretation of $u_x(0,t)$, $u_x(1,t)$ and a negative diffusivity constant in 1D Heat Equation on $(0,1)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, heat-equation

I'm looking for help with the following problem. We have the heat equation $u_t=Du_{xx}$ modelling the temperature across a conducting material, defined for $0<x<1, t>0$ with boundary conditions $u_x(0,t)=u_x(1,t)=0$ and initial condition $u(x,0)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & 0<x\leq a  \\
      0 & a<x<1 \\
   \end{cases}$.

Questions:

(i) What is the physical interpretation of the boundary conditions?

Attempt at solution: The difference in temperature at each of the boundaries? (Not quite sure what the partial derivative of $u$ w.r.t $x$ would represent?)

(ii) How would the solution be effected if $D<0$?

Attempt at solution: Temperature would be concentrating instead of spreading out so the solution would tend to infinity?

(iii) Solve the equation?

Attempt at solution: $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$ so by separation of variables we get $X(x)=\cos(n\pi x), n=0,1,...$ and $T(t)=e^{-n^2\pi^2Dt}$. Hence $u(x,t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_ne^{-n^2\pi^2Dt}\cos(n\pi x)$.

Using the I.C. we have $u(x,0)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cos(n\pi x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & 0<x\leq a  \\
      0 & a<x<1 \\
   \end{cases}$.

So for $a<x<1 $, we have $a_n=0$, hence $u(x,t)=0$ for $a<x<1 $.

For $0<x\leq a$, we have $a_n=\frac{\int_0^1\cos(n\pi x)}{\int_0^1\cos^2(n\pi x)}=2\int_0^1\cos(n\pi x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & n=0 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise} \\
   \end{cases}$

Hence solution is $u(x,t)=1$ for $0<x\leq a$?

To me this doesn't seem correct as the following question asks about the solution's decaying behaviour, yet from my computations the solution remains the same for all $t$? Any help on where I've gone wrong would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I've now computed $a_n$ by using $a_n=2\left(\int_0^a\cos(n\pi x)dx+\int_a^1 0dx\right)$ for $n>0$, so is it true that $u(x,t)=a+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi a)e^{-n^2\pi^2Dt}\cos(n\pi x)$?

Comment: Regarding the interpretation of the boundary conditions (i): do you know what "heat flux" is? Regarding (iii) $a_n$ cannot depend on $x$, hint: think Fourier transform

Comment: I'm aware of the concept of flux with regards to 'magnetic flux', so I'm guessing heat flux is the same idea? For (iii) do you mean take the Fourier transform $u(x,0)$?

Comment: Heat flux is the spatial derivative of the temperature and represents the flow of heat https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_flux. for iii that is what I mean, you need to find the values of $a_n$ that make the $0-1$ step.

Comment: I've now computed $a_n$ by instead using $a_n=2\left(\int_0^a\cos(n\pi x)dx+\int_a^1 0dx\right)$ for $n>0$, so is it true that $u(x,t)=a+\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2}{n\pi}\sin(n\pi a)e^{-n^2\pi^2Dt}\cos(n\pi x)$? Also was I correct about part (ii)? Thank you.